# What happen when you use select# as a css selector?

Tags: javascript, scripting

I found these two element selectors: `select#usuario-select` and `#usuario-select`. Would they return the same node in case I use them as a `document.querySelector()` parameter?

Comment: Please, they me if you find my question annoying or if it contain any mistake

Comment: Actually, it is not valid to use "usuario-select" without any prefix of class '.' or id '#' in both document.querySelector() and jquery style.

Comment: @HouyNarun - if you have an element `<usuario-select>` then `usuario-select` will *select* them

Comment: `Would they return the same node` - no ... one selects the `<select id="usuario-select" ...>` the other selects the first `<usuario-select>` - `#` in a selector indicates you are selecting by `id` (which is unique, right)

Comment: @JaromandaX, ah sure it is, supposed he, questioner, use this tag for his specific purpose, likely in `xml` element. :)

Comment: Well, I've just checked the questing and I find something wrong: I meant "#usuario-select" instead of "usuario-select". Sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), as you said. [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) looks for the first element matching the provided CSS selector. So:

`document.querySelector('select#usuario-select')` looks for the first *select* tag with id *usuario-select* ( `<select id='usuario-select'>`)

`document.querySelector('#usuario-select')` looks for the first *any* tag with an id *usuario-select* (`<ANYTAG id='usuario-select'>`)

They would return the same node *if* the first element with id `usuario-select` is a `select` tag.

Comment: You could also use `document.getElementById('usuario-select')`. Notice that _doesn't_ have a `#` – just the id string.

Comment: Well, It would work as long as tag type doesn't matter, right? @SamVK

Answer (score 0):

You may find this link helpful. 
[1]https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

This sign # just simply change the text of an element with id= usuario-select

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the `#` character is used as an [ID Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors#ID_selectors).

If you have a DOM element with the `id` attribute set; a corresponding ID Selector can be used to query for this node.

**Example:**

```css
// This is a Class Selector. It'll query for the parent div because
// it has a `class` attribute with a matching identifier.
.parent {
  background-color: black;
}

// This is an ID Selector. It'll query for the H1 text element because
// it has a `id` attribute with a matching identifier.
#name {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

// This is an Element Selector AND an ID Selector. It'll query for
// and `<img/>` DOM node that has a matching `id` attribute value.
img#avatar {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img id="avatar" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
  <h1 id="name">John Doe</h1>
</div>
```

---

**MDN is a great resource for learning more about selectors**:

- [Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors)
- [Simple selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors)
- [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [Pseudo classes and pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements)
- [Combinators and multiple selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors)

---

As for your final question of "would (a css selector) return the same node as (the) `document.querySelector` (function)?", yes.

The `Document.querySelector` documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

It states the following:

**Syntax**
`element = document.querySelector(selectors);`

**Parameters:**

> **selectors**:
>
> A DOMString containing one or more selectors to match.
>
> This string
>   must be a valid CSS selector string; if it isn't, a SYNTAX_ERR exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As far I as understand your question,

**"select#usuario-select" Vs. "#usuario-select"**

`select#usuario-select` this will select `select` element with ID `#usuario-select` your selection is specifically target `select` element only.

While `#usuario-select` this will select an element with ID `#usuario-select`, you don't target which element.

Since rule of thumb of CSS, ID would be always unique; therefore only one element with specified ID will be selected and returned.

Back to your question, will they return the same? - It depends on your HTML.

Suppose your HTML Makeup is like this:

```
<select id="usuario-select">
<option value="a">Apple</option>
<option value="b">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Then, either `document.querySelector("select#usuario-select")` or `document.querySelector("#usuario-select")` will return the same node.

However, if your HTML Makup is like this:

```
<p id="usuario-select">Hey, I has ID "#usuario-select"</p>
```

Then, the first select expression `document.querySelector("select#usuario-select")` will return `none` because there is not `select` element with ID `usuario-select`, insead `document.querySelector("#suario-select")` will return the paragraph element, the same select expression for this is `document.querySelector("p#usuario-select")` also return the same.

Hope this help.